# DataFrame column with nothing values in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand how DataFrames work in Julia and I am having a rough time.

I usually worked with DataFrames --in Python-- adding new columns on every simulation step and populating each row with values.

For example, I have this DataFrame which contains input Data:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame( A=Int[], B=Int[] )
push!(df, [1, 10])
push!(df, [2, 20])
push!(df, [3, 30])
```

Now, let's say that I do calculations based on those `A` and `B` columns that generate a third column `C` with DateTime objects. But DateTime objects are not generated for all rows, they could be null.

1. How is that use case handled in Julia?
2. How shall I create the new C column and assign values inside the `for r in eachrow(df)`?

```
# Pseudocode of what I intend to do

df[! :C] .= nothing

for r in eachrow(df)
    if condition
        r.C = mySuperComplexFunctionThatReturnsDateTimeForEachRow()
    else
        r.C = nothing
    end
end
```

To give a runable and concrete code, let's fake condition and function:

```
df[! :C] .= nothing

for r in eachrow(df)
    if r.A == 2
        r.C = Dates.now()
    else
        r.C = nothing
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The efficient pattern to do this is:

```
df.C = f.(df.A, df.B)
```

where `f` is a function that takes scalars and calculates an output based on them (i.e. your simulation code) and you pass to it the columns you need to extract from `df` to perform the calculations. In this way the Julia compiler will be able to generate fast (type-stable) native code.

In your example the function `f` would be `ifelse` so you could write:

```
df.C = ifelse.(df.A .== 2, Dates.now(), nothing)
```

Also consider if you return `nothing` or `missing` (they have a different interpretation in Julia: `nothing` means absence of a value and `missing` means that the value is present but is not known; I am not sure which would be better in your case).

Comment: I will try this approach. Thanks, it helps to understand better how to work in Julia.

Comment: This is a particular application of https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#kernel-functions-1 performance recommendation which will be relevant for you in performance-critical code.

Comment: Thanks I will check the link

Comment: Just to add to Kaminski answer.. In many Julia operations, using a `nothing` would led to run-time errors, while a `missing` would led to `missing` propagate silently. If you go for the missing case, don't forget to define your DataFrame column as `Union{T,Missing}`, e.g. `Union{Float64,Missing}`.

Answer (score 4):

If you initialize the column with `df[!, :C] .= nothing` it has the element type `Nothing`. When writing `DateTime`s to this column, Julia is attempting to convert them to `Nothing` and fails.
I am not sure if this is the most efficient or recommended solution, but if you initialize the column as a union of `DateTime` and `Nothing`

```
df[!, :C] = Vector{Union{DateTime, Nothing}}(nothing, size(df, 1))
```

your example should work.

Comment: Thanks, I have also noticed that I can create an array `C = []` which seems to be of type `Any` and then `push!` elements in the `for eachrow(df)` loop. After the loop it is possible to just append `C` to the dataframe `df.C = C`.

Comment: It is not recommended to create vectors of type `Any` (unless you really have to), because later using them will be slow (the compiler does not know what is the type of values they hold).

Comment: Perfect answer! I'd use `nrow(df)` instead of `size(df, 1)`, which is 20 ns faster on my laptop ;-)